# How to add reference of the caller of the method?

Tags: java

Okay, I couldn't think of a better title for my problem.

I have a timer thread. It ticks and after enough ticks, I want it to call a method of the thing that called it. If anybody has ever used Unity, I'm trying to do this:

```cs
public void test(String CallMeLater){
   Invoke(CallMeLater);  // Unity
   caller.CallMeLater(); // Idea
}
```

It's worth noting the thing calling it is not static. **How can I do this?**

Here is what I have:

**CLOCK**

```java
public class Clock extends Thread {
   Object test;

   public Clock(int minutes, Object test) {
      this.minutes = minutes;
      this.test = test;
   }

   public void run() {
      try {
         Thread.sleep(1000);
      } catch(Exception err) {}

      test.SayHi();
      run();
   }
}
```

**CALLER**

```java
public class MainWindow {
   // When the Clock is created i want to pass "this" into it.
   app.Clock clock = new app.Clock(60, this); 

   public MainWindow(){
      // Creates frame, and add listeners. I cut it out. 
      // It has nothing to do with the problem at hand
   }

   private void Set(){
      // This is where i start the timer
      clock.start();  
   }

   public void SayHi(){
      System.out.println("Hi");
   }
}
```

Comment: You want to call a call back method, presumably to provide some kind event notification? Then you need a reference to the object that originally called/started the timer...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yep. Thats what i want to do. Thats what i asking how to do. How do i reference the object that originally started it?

Comment: Pass the caller as argument in this method or declare a field with the type of the callers of these methods.

Comment: could you please post the complete code for your test method . Do you have *called* instance available in the test method?

Comment: Pass the instance of your caller class by using the _this_ keyword, and then call the appropriate method from the other class.

Comment: Basically you've described a [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html), you need to pass the timer class a instance of the object which called it, presumably implementing some kind of common interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Callbacks are a good use case for an Interface.

```
public Inteface Callback {
    public void complete();
}

public class Ticker {
    public void test(Callback callback) {
        // tick, tick, tick
        callback.complete();
    }
}

public class User implements Callback {
    public void complete() {
        ...
    }

    public void useTicker() {
        Ticker ticker = new Ticker();
        ticker.test(this);
    }
}
```

Note that Java has a number of built in intefaces that look exactly like this. In fact the Timer class has a good example: TimerTask which does exactly what you are looking for here.

Comment: Thank you. I feel really stupid for not knowing about "CallBacks" or the idea of them. But, none the less i wont make that mistake again.